# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in your code on line 3 (PHP)

Tags: php, function, if-statement, mktime

So im having issue with my code. Im trying to implement multiple mktime functions to PHP code using if and else if values but still im getting something wrong. I dont know what could be wrong. I get error PHP check online and i have fixed the code abit, but still i get the error
Here is the code

```
<?
// Check if clock is 4:20am/4:20pm (12h clock) or 4:20/16:20 (24h clock)
if (time() = mktime(4,20,0,0,0,0));
    require_once('doc.html');
else if
    (time() > mktime (4,20,0,0,0,0));
    require_once('doc2.html');
else if
    (time() = mktime(16,20,0,0,0,0));
    require_once('doc2.tml');
else if
    (time() > mktime(16,20,0,0,0,0));
    require_once('doc2.html');
?>
```

Comment: `=` is assign. Use `==` in the if conditions.

Comment: Why's these many minus for an OP making just his second question showing effort

Comment: You might want to read the following help pages: ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). These pages will help you to improve your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Check if clock is 4:20am/4:20pm (12h clock) or 4:20/16:20 (24h clock)
if (time() == mktime(4,20,0,0,0,0)) {
    require_once('doc.html');
} else if {
    (time() > mktime (4,20,0,0,0,0));
    require_once('doc2.html');
} else if {
    (time() == mktime(16,20,0,0,0,0));
    require_once('doc2.tml');
} else if {
    (time() > mktime(16,20,0,0,0,0));
    require_once('doc2.html');
}
```

Your must use `==` statement for check equals.

Comment: Well now it tells me that i have Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in your code on line 5

Comment: dont forget the {} brackets on more than 1 lines of blocks

Comment: -1, I cant beleive,How did OP accepted this error code.How could you have `if` without conditions ?